# How to bind {{items | sum }} outside a template repeat?

Tags: polymer

```
        <div id="order">
            <template repeat="{{items as item}}">
                <p data-id="{{item.id}}" data-qty="{{item.qty}}" data-price="{{item.price}}">
                    <span>- {{item.id}}</span>
                    <span> x{{item.qty}}</span>
                </p>
            </template>
            <p>- Total {{total}}&#8364;</p>
        </div>
```

Tried `itemsChanged` first to update the total but that did not work because the observer does not look at the property `items[id].qty`

The documentation does mention a more specific observer but can not use it when items is a array.

`{{items | sum }}` fails too because it only updates one time at start up.

Last option is

```
var order = this.$.order
order.onMutation(order, this.sum)
```

But then polymer crashes without a error message. I just see a blank screen when I put it in `ready:function(){...}`

Comment: you're using `{{items as item}}` instead of `{{item in items}}`. The `as` is only used as an alias to rename variables. You can see what I mean if you replace all your subsequent `{{item.<attribute>}}` by just `{{<attribute>}}` it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's not doable right now. or maybe with some crazy hack.

let me suggest that solution:

I have created simple polymer and use power of [Computed properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#evaluating-expressions)

```
<polymer-element name="x-repeat">
    <template>
        <template repeat="{{items as item}}">
            <div>{{item.q}}</div>
        </template>
        <div>Total is {{total}}</div>
    </template>
    <script>

        Polymer({
            items : [],
            created : function () {
                this.items = [{q:1}, {q:2}];
            },
            computed: { // NOTE: computed set 
                total: 'items | sum'
            },
            sum : function (items) { // NOTE : defined 'pipeline' function
                var total = 0;
                items.forEach(function (i) {
                    total += i.q;
                });
                return total;
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This almost works :D Meaning it calculates the `total` correctly but only once at startup. When the `q` values changes only `q` inside the `repeat="{{items as item}}"` template get updated while `total` stays the same :)

Comment: Can you add a `items[ ].q` observer to your code please.